# Cloning Windows 7 from a 32-bit machine to a 64-bit machine

Tags: windows-7

I bought a new laptop running on 64-bit processors. I want to migrate my old 32-bit Windows 7 to the new machine.

Ideally, I want to keep everything the same, e.g. files, software, profile, etc.

Is there any good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using Windows Easy Transfer: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer. Should already be installed.

Comment: does that copy installed software too?